# Conditional WHERE in realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm moving my app from sqlite3 to realm.

In my old code the queries were collective, i.e. code checks some settings and contemplating those builds a proper query:

**Pseudocode - how it was before:**

```
var str_where = "alala";
IF (SOMETHING) {
    str_where += "asdfasdfdasf";
}else{
    if (ANOTHERTHING)
        str_where += "trampampam";
    else
        str_where += "blablabla";
}

query+= "WHERE " + str_where

EXECUTE(query);
```

And now I don't have any query strings to pass and execute. With the Realm my query looks like:

**Pseudocode - how it looks like now:**

```
IF (SOMETHING) {
    dbPhrases = realm.where(xPhrase.class)
    .contains("alala")
    .contains("asdfasdfdasf")
    .findAll();
}else{
    if (ANOTHERTHING)
         dbPhrases = realm.where(xPhrase.class)
        .contains("alala")
        .contains("trampampam")
        .findAll();
    else
        dbPhrases = realm.where(xPhrase.class)
        .contains("alala")
        .contains("blablabla")
        .findAll();
}
```

And it looks very ugly and messy

So Is there any way to use some variable or maybe `RealmQuery` (which I wasn't able to implement) to construct the query along the way and then execute it in the end as I was doing it until now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RealmQuery<xPhrase> query = realm.where(xPhrase.class).contains("alala");
if (SOMETHING) {
    query.contains("asdfasdfdasf");
} else if (ANOTHERTHING) {
    query.contains("trampampam")
} else {
    query.contains("blablabla");
}
dpPhrases = query.findAll();
```

Comment: Just not to start another thread, is there any support for wildcards in Realm? Or alternatively, how to execute sql's SELECT * WHERE SOMETHING LIKE "Bla%", so the string will start with 'Bla' and end with anything there is?

Comment: Not, yet. You can see the progress on https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1377 . Also, RealmQuery.contains() might solve part of your problems.

Comment: Try `RealmQuery.beginsWith()`